# Intersection multiplicity with a non-tangent line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $V$ be an algebraic variety and $x$ a point of $V$ and $\ell$ a line passing through $x$ such that $\ell$ is not included in the tangeant space $T_{V,x}$.
It seems intuitive that the intersection multiplicity $i(\ell,V;x)$ should be $1$, but how to prove it?

Comment: What if $x$ is a singular point?

Comment: Well, in my context we can restrict ourselve to singular points, however a priori this looks true even if $x$ is singular.

Comment: For the α cubic (ordinary double point at origin), the intersection multiplicity for a line ‘in general position’ is  `2`.

Comment: I meant **regular** points of course.

Comment: In this case, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Your variety $V$ should be embedded in projective (or affine) space, since otherwise you cannot speak of a "line". As your question is local, you can assume that $V$ is a subvariety of the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ and your point $x$ is the origin $0$. Clearly the tangent space $T_0 \ell$ of $\ell$ in $0$ is just the line $\ell$ itself, when we consider $T_0 \ell$ as a subspace of $T_0 \mathbb{A}^n = \mathbb{A}^n$. 
If I understand your assumption correctly, the intersection of 
$T_0 \ell$ and $T_0 V$ inside $T_0 \mathbb{A}^n$ is just $0$. Thus after
blowing up $\mathbb{A}^n$ in $0$, the strict transform of $V$
and $\ell$ do not intersect in the exceptional divisor. Hence, $i(\ell, V; x) = 1$.

Comment: Could you detail more the last sentence please?

Comment: For this you should provide a definition of $i(\ell, V; x)$

Comment: The one I use is Hartshorne's. In this context it gives $$\quad i(\ell,V;x) = \mathrm{len}_{S_\mathfrak{M}} (S/(I_V + I_\ell))_{\mathfrak{M}}$$ where $\mathfrak M$ is the maximal ideal corresponding to $x$

Comment: ...and $S=k[X_1, \dots, X_n]$

Comment: I edited my answer, is it now clear?

Comment: Well, I don't know the notions of blow up nor exceptionnal divisor.

Comment: Okay. You can also see it with your definition: Since $\ell$ is a line in $\mathbb{A}^n$, you can assume after a linear coordinate change that $\ell$ is given by the zero set $X_2 = \ldots = X_n = 0$. Thus $S / I_{\ell} = k[X_1]$. Since $T_0 V$ and $T_0 \ell$ intersect only in $0$, this says that $(S / I_V + I_{\ell})_{(X_1, \ldots, X_n)} \simeq (k[X_1] / (X_1))_{(X_1)} \simeq k$

Comment: I asked a similar but more complicated question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234097/intersection-multiplicity-with-a-hyperplane