# intersection multiplicity with a hyperplane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, intersection-theory

Let $V$ be an algebraic variety embedded in $\mathbb P^n$. Let $H$ be a hyperplane (that is to say, a variety defined by a single equation of degree $1$) such that for every $x \in H \cap V$, $x$ is a regular point of $V$, and $H$ does not contain the tangent space $T_V,x$. I want to show that the intersection multiplicity of $V$ and $H$ along each irreducible component is $1$, but I did not manage to. Any indications?

Comment: What is your definition of intersection multiplicity ? What did you try ?

Comment: I use Hartshorne's definition: the intersection multiplicity of $V$ and $H$ along the irreducible component $Z$, whose homogeneous ideals are respectively $I_V$, $I_H$ and $\mathfrak P$, is the length of the $S_{\mathfrak P}$-module $(S/(I_H+I_V))_{\mathfrak P}$, where $S$ is the ring of polynomials. I've tried to figure out how to pass from the local information $T_{V,x} \not \subset H$ for all $x \in Z$ to a global information, but I have no clue. However, it is important that $H$ is an hyperplane and not any affine subspace, because I found counter-examples when $codim H=2$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the beginning of a solution. Let $x$ be in a component of intersection multiplicity at least 2. Let us show that if $x$ is regular then $T_x V \subset H$.
First, since everything is local, we can suppose we are in $\mathbb A^n$. After a base change, we can also suppose $H$ is defined by $X_1=0$.
Let $e \in (S/I_V+X)_{\mathfrak P}$ not in the class of $k$ (possible since this module has length at least 2 over $S_{\mathfrak P}$ by assumption).
Then $e^2, e^3, \dots$ is not free.
So we can write $\sum_{i=2}^m a^i e^i=0$ in $(S/I_V+X)_{\mathfrak P}$, with $a_i \in S_{\mathfrak P}$. Multiplying by the denominators, then taking a lift, this gives $ \sum_{i=2}^m b^i e^i=v+X_1g$ with $b_i, g \in S$ and $v \in I_V$.
We can suppose $e(x)=0$ because the class of $e-e(0)$ is not the class of $k$. 
Taking partial derivatives, we find that $\frac{\partial v}{\partial X_j}(x)=0$ except maybe for $j=1$.  Now to complete the proof, we should show that if $x$ is regular, then we can suppose $\frac{\partial v}{\partial X_1}(x) \neq 0$. For now I can't see how to do this.

Comment: I think the fact that H doesn't contain the tangent space will help in completing your proof.

Comment: Well, I proceed by contraposition: I suppose the intersection multiplicity is at least 2 and $x$ is regular, so I want to prove that $T_xV \subset H$...